# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,191.94630872…". error with d3 and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to integrate D3 with react, Please find the code snippet below.

In the code I am trying to implement a simple line in D3 and react. But I end up getting `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,191.94630872…`

There are similar questions on stackoverflow, but they are not helping either.

[attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…". react with d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447509/attribute-d-expected-number-mnan-nanlnan-nanl-react-with-d3)

["Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…". " Error with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846158/error-path-attribute-d-expected-number-mnan-nanlnan-nanl-error-with)

A Couple of things I tried doing.

A: Initially I thought there is some problem with the date parsing, So I changed my `day` key to `number` and removed date parse, I ended up having the same error.

B: A assumed there is some problem with the domain declaration for x and y. I removed extend and gave a discrete value, still facing the same error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";

class LineChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {selected: props.width || null};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    }

    render() {
        let data=[
            {day:'02-11-2016',count:180},
            {day:'02-12-2016',count:250},
            {day:'02-13-2016',count:150},
            {day:'02-14-2016',count:496},
            {day:'02-15-2016',count:140},
            {day:'02-16-2016',count:380},
            {day:'02-17-2016',count:100},
            {day:'02-18-2016',count:150}
        ];

        let margin = {top: 5, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
            w = this.state.width - (margin.left + margin.right),
            h = this.props.height - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

        let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m-%d-%Y");
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.day);
        });

        let x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.date;
            }))
            .range([0, w]);

        let y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([ 0 , d3.max( data, function(d) {
                return d.count + 100;
            })])
            .range([ h, 0 ]);

        let line = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.date);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.count);
            }).curve(d3.curveCardinal);

        let transform = 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')';
        return (
            <div>
                <p>LineChart</p>
                <svg id={this.props.chartId} width={this.state.width} height={this.props.height}>
                    <g transform={transform}>
                        <path className="line shadow" d={line(data)} strokeLinecap="round"/>
                    </g>            
                </svg>
            </div>
      )
    }
  }

  LineChart.defaultProps = {
    width: 800,
    height: 300,
    chartId: 'v1_chart'
  }
  export default LineChart;
```

Comment: You are using `this.state.width` to initialize `w`. This will be `undefined` resulting in `w` being `NaN`, hence the error. As can be seen from this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0tf0vsg/) the rest of the code runs fine. Use `this.props.width` to get the width much like you do for the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake at this string:

```
w = this.state.width - (margin.left + margin.right)
```

If you put `console.log(this.state.width)` you get `undefined`. You use `w` variable for d3 scales, so they produce incorrect values.
You can pass chart `width` as component props this way:

```
<LineChart width={600} height={300} />
```

And specify `w` variable:

```
    let margin = {top: 5, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
        w = this.props.width - (margin.left + margin.right), // <== !!!
        h = this.props.height - (margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

Check the working demo below:

```js
class LineChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {selected: props.width || null};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    }

    render() {
        let data=[
            {day:'02-11-2016',count:180},
            {day:'02-12-2016',count:250},
            {day:'02-13-2016',count:150},
            {day:'02-14-2016',count:496},
            {day:'02-15-2016',count:140},
            {day:'02-16-2016',count:380},
            {day:'02-17-2016',count:100},
            {day:'02-18-2016',count:150}
        ];

        let margin = {top: 5, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
            w = this.props.width - (margin.left + margin.right),
            h = this.props.height - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

        let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m-%d-%Y");
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.day);
        });

        let x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.date;
            }))
            .range([0, w]);

        let y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([ 0 , d3.max( data, function(d) {
                return d.count + 100;
            })])
            .range([ h, 0 ]);

        let line = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.date);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.count);
            }).curve(d3.curveCardinal);

        let transform = 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')';
        return (
            <div>
                <p>LineChart</p>
                <svg id={this.props.chartId} width={this.state.width} height={this.props.height}>
                    <g transform={transform}>
                        <path className="line shadow" d={line(data)} strokeLinecap="round"/>
                    </g>            
                </svg>
            </div>
      )
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(
  <LineChart width={600} height={200} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```